# WebDeveloper Database webform tables - Input version like gridview for output

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

In visual Web devlepoer I have my database connection in my project if My project database has several tables that I want users to entered data to into my webform and be submitted to my database is there an easy way to replicate my tables fields in a form. Like gridview for input.

I can manually sit here and create tables and add textboxes etc in html but seems a little redundant when the tables are already visible in the database explorer.

Want to be sure I am not taking the long version of an easy process. There are plenty of easy forms and tables for viewing database data but what about for submitting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back-end is completely Separate from the UI. At a later date it might be decided to group the fields in a different order, etc. Using a GridView only adds unnecessary overhead.

From a UI design perspective, you should not have too many form fields on a single page as the user is less likely to complete the form - basic usability issue. If this is the case, try splitting up the fields using a Wizard control and perhaps keep the user informed of their progress ( page 2 of 5, etc.).

Comment: @IrishCheiftan.  The tables I am current doing are for administrator not user to enter weekly sports stats so their are more than a few columns and rows to the tables.